# Optimizing alpha and beta in negative log likehood sum for beta binomial distribution

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I'm attempting to create sigma/summation function with the variables in my dataset that looks like this:

```
paste0("(choose(",zipdistrib$Leads[1],",",zipdistrib$Starts[1],")*beta(a+",zipdistrib$Starts[1],",b+",zipdistrib$Leads[1],"-",zipdistrib$Starts[1],")/beta(a,b))")
```

When I enter that code, I get

```
[1] "(choose(9,6)*beta(a+6,b+9-6)/beta(a,b))"
```

I want to create a sigma/summation function where `a` and `b` are unknown free-floating variables and the values of `Leads[i]` and `Starts[i]` are determined by the values for `Leads` and `Starts` for observation `i` in my dataset. I have tried using a `sum` function in conjunction with `mapply` and `sapply` to no avail. Currently, I am taking the tack of creating the function as a string using a `for` loop in conjunction with a `paste0` command so that the only things that change are the values of the variables `Leads` and `Starts`. Then, I try coercing the result into a function. To my surprise, I can actually enter this code without creating a syntax error, but when I try optimize the function for variables `a` and `b`, I'm not having success.

Here's my attempt to create the function out of a string.

```
betafcn <- function (a,b) {
abfcnstring <- 
  for (i in 1:length(zipdistrib$Zip5))
    toString(
      paste0("      (choose(",zipdistrib$Leads[i],",",zipdistrib$Starts[i],")*beta(a+",zipdistrib$Starts[i],",b+",zipdistrib$Leads[i],"-",zipdistrib$Starts[i],")/beta(a,b))+")
   )
as.function(
  as.list(
    substr(abfcnstring, 1, nchar(abfcnstring)-1) 
  )
)
}
```

Then when I try to optimize the function for a and b, I get the following:

```
optim(c(a=.03, b=100), betafcn(a,b))
## Error in as.function.default(x, envir) : 
  argument must have length at least 1
```

Is there a better way for me to compile a `sigma` from `i=1` to length of dataset with `mapply` or `lapply` or some other `*apply` function? Or am I stuck using a dreaded `for` loop? And then once I create the function, how do I make sure that I can optimize for `a` and `b`?

**Update**

This is what my dataset would look like:

```
leads <-c(7,4,2)
sales <-c(3,1,0)
zipcodes <-factor(c("11111", "22222", "33333"))
zipleads <-data.frame(ZipCode=zipcodes, Leads=leads, Sales=sales)
zipleads
##  ZipCode Leads Sales
# 1   11111     7     3
# 2   22222     4     1
# 3   33333     2     0
```

My goal is to create a function that would look something like this:

```
betafcn <-function (a,b) {
   (choose(7,3)*beta(a+3,b+7-3)/beta(a,b))+
   (choose(4,1)*beta(a+4,b+4-1)/beta(a,b))+
   (choose(2,0)*beta(a+0,b+2-0)/beta(a,b))
  }
```

The difference is that I would ideally like to replace the dataset values with any other possible vectors for Leads and Sales.

Comment: I'm not sure how best to begin helping you. First, are you aware of what `choose(7285,341)` will return? Try running it and you might decide to take a different approach, mathematically. Second, this whole "create a function from a string" approach is totally wrong and should be abandoned in favor of some basic R tutorials on creating functions, I think.

Comment: Let's say that for the sake of argument the values for m sub 1 and x sub 1 are m1=9 and x1=6. I have changed the question to reflect this. How would you create a sum of the beta functions with the beta function expressed as a function of both fixed and free-floating variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since R vectorizes most of its operations by default, you can write an expression in terms of single values of `a` and `b` (which will automatically be recycled to the length of the data) and vectors of `x` and `y` (i.e., `Leads` and `Sales`); if you compute on the log scale, then you can use `sum()` (rather than `prod()`) to combine the results. Thus I think you're looking for something like:

```
betafcn <- function(a,b,x,y,log=FALSE) {
   r <- lchoose(x,y)+lbeta(a+x,b+x-y)-lbeta(a,b)
   if (log) r else exp(r)
}
```

Note that (1) `optim()` *minimizes* by default (2) if you're trying to optimize a likelihood you're better off optimizing the log-likelihood instead ...

Since all of the internal functions (`+`, `lchoose`, `lbeta`) are vectorized, you should be able to apply this across the whole data set via:

```
zipleads <- data.frame(Leads=c(7,4,2),Sales=c(3,1,0))
objfun <- function(p) {  ## negative log-likelihood
    -sum(betafcn(p[1],p[2],zipleads$Leads,zipleads$Sales,
         log=TRUE))
}
objfun(c(1,1))
optim(fn=objfun,par=c(1,1))
```

I got crazy answers for this example (extremely large values of both shape parameters), but I think that's because it's awfully hard to fit a two-parameter model to three data points!

Since the shape parameters of the beta-binomial (which is what this appears to be) have to be positive, you might run into trouble with unconstrained optimization.  You can use `method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0,0)` or optimize the parameters on the log scale ...

Comment: The first function appears to work fine, but I get this error for the optim function:

    `Error in lbeta(a + y, b + x - y) : 
argument "b" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In a + y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Answer (score 1):

I thought your example was hopelessly complex. If you are going to attemp making a function by pasting character values, you first need to understand *how* to make a function body with an unevaluated expression, and after that basic task is understood, then you can elaborate ... if in fact it is necessary, noting BenBolker's suggestions.

```
choosefcn <- function (a,b) {}
txtxpr <- paste0("choose(",9,",",6,")" )
body(choosefcn) <- parse(text= txtxpr)
#----------
> betafcn
function (a, b) 
choose(9, 6)

val1 <- "a"
val2 <- "b"
txtxpr <- paste0("choose(", val1, ",", val2, ")" )
body(choosefcn) <- parse(text= txtxpr)
#
choosefcn 
#function (a, b) 
#choose(a, b)
```

It also possible to configure the formal arguments separately with the `formals<-` function. See each of these help pages:

```
?formals
?body
?'function'   # needs to be quoted
```